Writing back in Database using Power Apps without giving database access?
I have created a form to write back into the a Power BI database table using Power Apps but I have more than 200 users who are going to use it so I don't want to give database access or Power BI license.
Is there any way around it?
Appropriate solution

You can use multiple logins with the same Power BI account simultaneously. If you don't want to use a database for storing the info you could use a different datasource, like a file (Excel) or a folder (sharepoint, onedrive etc).
This video explains it well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPHwjPRnRwE
